# UnsupportedOperationException when deleting copy of RealmResult

Tags: android, list, arraylist, realm, realm-list

There is no `from` or `to` method to select data from DB in Realm, when i try to use `between()`, I get an unnecessary item at the end of result so I want to delete it after getting its copy to new `listObject`.

But even after making copy of it in another list object i am not being able to delete the last item in the `realmResult`.

```
RealmResults<CalendarDto> currentMonthDTOList = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(CalendarDto.class).between("primaryDayId", startingDayPrimaryKey, endingDayPrimaryKey).findAll().sort("primaryDayId", Sort.ASCENDING);
List<CalendarDto> currentList = currentMonthDTOList;
currentList.remove(currentList.size());
```

But i get the error saying unsupportedOperationException.

My log cat looks like this

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.toyanathpatro.gurkha, PID: 17714
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.toyanathpatro.gurkha/com.toyanathpatro.gurkha.activities.DashBoardActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: io.realm.RealmResults cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: io.realm.RealmResults cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    at com.toyanathpatro.gurkha.fragments.GridCalendarFragment.fetchData(GridCalendarFragment.java:84)
    at com.toyanathpatro.gurkha.fragments.GridCalendarFragment.onCreateView(GridCalendarFragment.java:42)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:601)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build a query to exclude the unwanted one instead of removing it later.

Try this:

```
RealmResults<CalendarDto> results = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(CalendarDto.class)
    .greaterThanOrEqualTo("primaryDayId", startingDayPrimaryKey)
    .lessThan("primaryDayId", endingDayPrimaryKey)
    .findAll().sort("primaryDayId", Sort.ASCENDING);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `List<CalendarDto> currentList = currentMonthDTOList;` as `currentMonthDTOList` is a `RealmResults<CalendarDto>` and not a `List<CalendarDto>`

If you want to remove the last object you can do ([documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/1.0.1/api/io/realm/RealmResults.html#deleteLastFromRealm--)):

```
currentMonthDTOList.deleteLastFromRealm();
```

As you don't want to remove the object from the database, you can make a copy of the results into a `List` and operate with it:

```
List<CalendarDto> dtos = new ArrayList<>();
dtos.addAll(currentMonthDTOList);
dtos.remove(dtos.size());
```

Comment: But that will remove that particular row from database too right ? thats not acceptable in my case, is there any way i can remove the last from the result i got ?

Comment: Yes, this will also remove ir from the database. What realm version are you using?

Comment: It's the stable version recently published

Comment: How can I not delete the copy of an object ? It's a new copy object right ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to copy to a `List` you can try to copy to a `RealmList` by so:

```
RealmList <CalendarDto> currentList = new RealmList<CalendarDto>();
currentList.addAll(yourRealmResults.subList(0, yourRealmResults.size()));
```

Although I've seen this working for people, I must quote [Realm.io news](https://realm.io/news/realm-java-0.87.0/) here:

> Work-in-progress
>
> While we are shipping initial support for RxJava now, we still lack Observable support for `RealmQuery` and `RealmList`. These will be added in a future update.

Additionally, you can try the new [`copyFromRealm()`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#copyFromRealm-E-) method and update the DB using [`copyToRealmOrUpdate()`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#copyToRealmOrUpdate-E-) method.